# saving values from radio buttons to database. rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

I'm adding radio buttons to my page.
I want the user to be able to pick whether the order gets sent or they pick it up.

I'm having troubles to save the values to the database.

can someone advise me?

```
    <div class="col-md-5 pick-up-buttons" id="country_div">

    <li><%= f.radio_button :pick_up, true %></li>
    <li><%= f.label :pick_up, "Pick up order in store", :value => "false"  %></li>


    <li><%= f.radio_button :pick_up, false, :checked => true %></li>
    <li><%= f.label :pick_up, "have the order delivered", :value => "true" %></li>

  </div>
```

here is the schema_file

```
  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "country"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.boolean  "shipped",    default: false
    t.string   "pick_up"

  end
```

Comment: that should be the type boolean

Comment: ok... is there a way to change it?

Comment: you need to run another migration and update the datatype of field

Comment: if you want then i can give you the solutions

Comment: Thank you, that would be very nice of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run:

```
rails generate migration changeStringToBooleanOfPickup
```

then modified the generated migration file to:

```
change_column :orders, :pick_up, 'boolean USING CAST(pick_up AS boolean)'
```

then execute 
              rake db:migrate

Comment: I get this error messages when I do `rake db:migrate`    `PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "pick_up" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING pick_up::boolean".
: ALTER TABLE "orders" ALTER COLUMN "pick_up" TYPE boolean
`

Comment: fixed it by doing = `def change
   change_column :orders, :pick_up, 'boolean USING CAST(pick_up AS boolean)'
  end`

Comment: updated the answer yes you can do it by using it,is it working now?

Answer (score 1):

Datatype of `pickup` column should be boolean to save true/false value.

```
<%= f.radio_button :pick_up, "1", checked: @order.pick_up?, data: { question: 'Pick up order in store' } %> <%= f.label :pick_up, "Yes" %>
<%= f.radio_button :pick_up, "0", checked: @order.pick_up?, data: { question: 'have the order delivered?' } %> <%= f.label :pick_up, "No" %>
```

Comment: thak you for that but, how would I turn this to have the `'have the order delivered?'` default checked?

Comment: this might sound stupid, but were should the `value "1"`be inserted to the code?  I've tried to inserted but always get an error

Comment: try this: `<%= f.radio_button :pick_up, "1", checked: @order.pick_up?, data: { question: 'have the order delivered?' } %> <%= f.label :pick_up, "No" %>`

Comment: try `<%= f.radio_button :pick_up, "1", checked: true, data: { question: 'have the order delivered?' } %> <%= f.label :pick_up, "No" %>`